# What book has archer volley rules?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, ranged-attack

In what book (and preferably, page numbers) are the rules for archer volleys in D&D 3.5?

Comment: Note that 3.5 *also* uses the term “volley” to refer to certain classes of attack that involve a character making multiple simultaneous attacks at once, like Manyshot or *scorching ray*. It’s not really related to the notion of archer volleys (even though Manyshot typically involves archery), but just so you don’t get confused while googling or whatever.

Answer (score 12):

*Complete Warrior* introduced the **Arrow Volley** under Historical Tactics on page 124. *Heroes of Battle*'s **Volley of Arrows** on pages 68-70 greatly expands these rules.

But because both version requires at least 10 archers, PCs are more likely use **the teamwork benefits Indirect Fire and Missile Volley** on page 161 of the *Player's Handbook 2*.

Answer (score 7):

**Heroes of Battle, p68** - *Volley of Arrows* section.